# Deploying meteorJS 1.2 using Meteor-Up fails

Tags: meteor, deployment, production-environment, meteor-up

This application is Meteor-1.2.2. Hope Meteor-up is compatible with it. I have been trying to deploy to a production server using [Mup - Meteor Up](http://meteor-up.com/) but it keeps failing. I have been on this for about 3 days. The seup do pass successfully but the deployment failed at the compiling stage. what do I do?

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      username: 'serveradmin',
      // pem: './path/to/pem'
       password: 'serverpassword'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    // build with the debug mode on
    // You can deploy in debug mode by passing --debug.
    // This will leave your source code readable by your favorite in-browser debugger, just like it is in local development mode
    // :: Think Meteor Toys!
    "debug": true,

    // executable used to build the meteor project
    // you can set a local repo path if needed
    "executable": "meteor"
  },

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": false,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.33 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.40", 

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": false,


  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'crowducate',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      port: 3300,
      ROOT_URL: 'https://course.rabboni.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://ken4ward:newpass123@ds243085.mlab.com:43085/rabbonidbserver',
    },

     ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
       autogenerate: {
         email: 'kehindeadeoya@gmail.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
         domains: 'course.rabboni.com,www.course.rabboni.com'
       }
     },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is using Meteor 1.3 or older
      image: 'kadirahq/meteord:base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true,
    "deployCheckWaitTime": 600
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

Error log

```
C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.deploy>mup.cmd deploy

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                     │
   │   update available 1.3.4 => 1.3.5   │
   │     To update, run npm i -g mup     │
   │                                     │
   └─────────────────────────────────────┘

loaded config from C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.deploy\mup.js

5 Validation Errors
  - "buildOptions" is an unknown property
  - "setupMongo" is an unknown property
  - "setupNode" is an unknown property
  - "nodeVersion" is an unknown property
  - "setupPhantom" is an unknown property

Read the docs and view example configs at
    http://meteor-up.com/docs

Building App Bundle Locally
Errors prevented bundling:
While minifying app code:

C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:196:18:
Unexpected token: punc (:)
at new JS_Parse_Error
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:196:18)
at js_error
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:204:11)
at croak
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:675:9)
at token_error
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:683:9)
at unexpected
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:689:9)
at semicolon
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:709:43)
at simple_statement
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:889:73)
at
C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:742:47
at
C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:722:24
at block_
(C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifiers\1.0.2\plugin.minifyStd.os\npm\minifiers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1002:20)



=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.

C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.deploy>

C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.deploy>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of where you need to read the errors and follow the advice. For example:

```
5 Validation Errors
  - "buildOptions" is an unknown property
  - "setupMongo" is an unknown property
  - "setupNode" is an unknown property
  - "nodeVersion" is an unknown property
  - "setupPhantom" is an unknown property
```

The only one of these that is valid is `buildOptions`, which needs to be inside a `meteor` block, like this:

```
meteor: {
  buildOptions: {
    // build with the debug mode on
    debug: true,
    // mobile setting for cordova apps
    mobileSettings: {
      public: {
        'meteor-up': 'rocks',
      }
    },
    // executable used to build the meteor project
    // you can set a local repo path if needed
    executable: 'meteor',
  }
}
```

I don't know where you got the others from. The parser is being nice to you, letting you know the options that are not valid.

Next it recommends that you read the documentation

> Read the docs and view example configs at 
>       http://meteor-up.com/docs

So my best advice is to read the instructions. One of the commands (I won't tell you which) will even generate a sample file which you can edit. MUP is really easy to use if you just follow the instructions. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel, I'd got it resolved earlier in the day. The new problem now is that it fails at starting the app.